# Design to aggregate multiple REST APIs and send the data to UI

Tags: rest

I have a requirement to aggregate multiple REST APIs and to send the data to UI.

One way I am thinking is to call all the REST APIs in multiple different threads and aggregate the result and send it to UI. In this way the time taken/latency is the time taken by the slowest REST API to return the data. Other way is to use a reactor style pattern, but I feel that will also take the same time.

Is there any other way to aggregate data faster from multiple REST APIs and send it to UI?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

What did you try? 

What are your inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: From the UI, we make a REST call and the service in the backend internally calls 5 other REST apis and aggregate data and send it to UI.
The easier way which we have now is to call the REST apis one by one and aggregate the data at the end and send the response, which is obviously slower and I want to optimize it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your comment and the async nature of the task you want to accomplish I would like to suggest using multithreading.

Here's my example about Python multithreading using a simple ping command, you can customize it and use it as a starter.

It also contains an explanation of the risks and advantages of using multithreading and a brief description of what is the GIL in Python:

```
# Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)
# 
# Python doesn't allow multi-threading in the truest sense of the word. It has a multi-threading package
# but if you want to multi-thread to speed your code up, then it's usually not a good idea to use it.
# Python has a construct called the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL).
# The GIL makes sure that only one of your 'threads' can execute at any one time.
# A thread acquires the GIL, does a little work, then passes the GIL onto the next thread.
# This happens very quickly so to the human eye it may seem like your threads are executing in parallel,
# but they are really just taking turns using the same CPU core.
# All this GIL passing adds overhead to execution.
# This means that if you want to make your code run faster then using the threading
# package often isn't a good idea.

# There are reasons to use Python's threading package.
# If you want to run some things simultaneously, and efficiency is not a concern,
# then it's totally fine and convenient.
# Or if you are running code that needs to wait for something (like some IO) then it could make a lot of sense.
# But the threading library won't let you use extra CPU cores.

# Multi-threading can be outsourced to the operating system (by doing multi-processing),
# some external application that calls your Python code (eg, Spark or Hadoop), or some code that your Python
# code calls (eg: you could have your Python code call a C function that does the expensive multi-threaded stuff).

# Why This Matters
# Because the GIL is an A-hole. Lots of people spend a lot of time trying to find bottlenecks in their fancy
# Python multi-threaded code before they learn what the GIL is.

# Once this is clear...
# Let's get our hands dirty :)

#!/bin/python
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
import time
import os

__author__ = "Davide Nastri"
__version__ = "0.1.0"
__license__ = "MIT"

pool_size = 5

def do_ping(ip):
    if os.name == 'nt':
        print ("Using Windows Ping to " + ip)
        proc = Popen(['ping', ip], stdout=PIPE)
        return proc.communicate()[0]
    else:
        print ("Using Linux Ping to " + ip)
        proc = Popen(['ping', ip, '-c', '4'], stdout=PIPE)
        return proc.communicate()[0]


os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
print ("Running using threads\n")
start_time = time.time()
pool = Pool(pool_size)
website_names = ["www.davidenastri.it", "www.google.com","www.facebook.com","www.pinterest.com","www.microsoft.com"]
result = {}
for website_name in website_names:
    result[website_name] = pool.apply_async(do_ping, args=(website_name,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
print ("\n--- Execution took {} seconds ---".format((time.time() - start_time)))

# Now we do the same without threading, just to compare time
print ("\nRunning NOT using threads\n")
start_time = time.time()
for website_name in website_names:
    do_ping(website_name)
print ("\n--- Execution took {} seconds ---".format((time.time() - start_time)))

# Here's one way to print the final output from the threads
output = {}
for key, value in result.items():
    output[key] = value.get()
print ("\nOutput aggregated in a Dictionary:")
print (output)
print ("\n")

print ("\nPretty printed output:")
for key, value in output.items():
    print (key + "\n")
    print (value)
```

Comment: Agree with this approach. This will still hold the caller thread until we get the response from all the 5 REST apis or the time taken will be equal to the slowest REST api. Is there any other better approach like using websockets where we return the caller thread immediately and post the response back as and when it is available.

Comment: What would you be returning?

Comment: Response is a JSON object which caller can consume.

Comment: What I mean is that if you get a request you can only provide one response.
For this reason I cannot imagine what you would like to return if not the complete data that was requested...

Comment: Hi @Lokn, if my answer was useful for you please consider upvoting it and/or choosing it as final answer. Thanks!